# PJAX / Masonry failing in Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, pjax

On my wordpress website (http://goo.gl/J8qrSE) I am using Masonry (masonry.desandro.com) and PJAX (https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) for transitions.

Everything works fine in Chrome & IE but in Firefox the homepage loads fine, you can click on a gallery (again, works fine), but when you click on the logo to go back to the homepage all the masonry images are stacked on top of each other like masonry hasn't run properly.

The weird thing is that it works perfectly if firebug is open (docked or in a separate window) but then it sometimes works / sometimes doesn't if firebug is closed.

I don't have any stray console.logs anywhere that I can find but it's hard to debug when it works every time I have firebug open.

Comment: You need to show a simplified example of the code problem here or it didn't happen and this will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try loading the script [imagesloaded.js](http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/) and then call masonry like this:

```
function domasonry() {
    var container = document.querySelector('#griddy');
    var msnry;

    imagesLoaded( container, function() {
      msnry = new Masonry( container, {
      itemSelector: '.item',
      columnWidth: '.item'
      });
    });
   };
```